# Generating a discrete random variable in Java?

Tags: java, random

Today in interview they asked me this question? How to generate a discrete random variable in Java? I couldn't do it but I wonder the solution.
They gave  me an array:

```
double[] probabilities={.2,.1,.3,.4};
double[] outcomes ={4,5,8,11.5};
```

And this should give the answer:

```
double discreteRV = problem.randPMF(probabilities,outcomes);
```

I couldn't understand how to solve this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since all the probabilities will always add up to 1, you can generate a random number between 0 and 1 then iterate through the probabilities and subtract them. When the number is less than or equal to 0, the index of the last subtracted probability is the index of the outcome:

```
import java.util.Random;
```

```
public static double randPMF(double[] prob, double[] out) {
    double rand = Math.random();
    int index = -1;
    while (rand >= 0) {
        index++;
        rand -= prob[index];
    }
    return out[index];
}
```

Comment: Looks like we had basically the same idea conceptually. I think yours may be cleaner though.

Comment: @xtratic Thanks! Great minds think alike

Comment: This code will, eventually, throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. `Math.random()` will eventually return 0.0. Trivially fixed with `while (rand >= 0.0)`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my idea for a solution:

```
private double randPMF(double[] probabilities, double[] outcomes) {
    double random = Math.random();
    double p = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < probabilities.length; i++) {
        p += probabilities[i];
        if (random < p) {
            return outcomes[i];
        }
    }
    return outcomes[outcomes.length - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with

```java
    private static double randPMF(double[] probabilities, double[] outcomes) {
        int n = 10;
        boolean nNotFound;
        for (double probability: probabilities){
            nNotFound = true;
            while(nNotFound)
            if (probability*n == (double)((int)(probability*n)))
                break;
            else
                n *= 10;
        }
        double[] numbers = new double[n];
        //j tracks the probability/occurence
        int j;
        //k tracks the new array
        int k = 0;
        //i tracks each element in our old arrays
        for (int i = 0; i<probabilities.length; i++) {
            j = 0;
            while (j < (probabilities[i]*n)) {
            numbers[k] = outcomes[i];
            k++;
            j++;
            }
        }
        int index = new Random().nextInt(n);
        System.out.println(numbers.length);
        return numbers[index];
    }
```

Comment: What if any of the probabilities are small like `.05`? I don't think this would work in that case.

Comment: @xtratic I've fixed that issue by making n (number of elements in the array we create) dynamic and dependent on the number of decimal places.

Comment: @xtratic I think your solution is more efficient than my by a long margin